# Fenced code block (with backticks) formatting fails with blank lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting

In [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897406/how-can-i-share-a-mockmvc-session-with-htmlunit), I tried to paste code using the triple-backtick syntax. However, when I did that, the backticks appeared to be treated as just ordinary text:

```
MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx)
    .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
    .build()

HtmlUnitDriver driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder.mockMvcSetup(mvc).javascriptEnabled(true).build()
```

This issue appears to be triggered if there are any blank-after-trim lines in the code block.

**edit**: In response to Martijn's answer that "they're not supported", they *do* work partially:

`This is in code formatting.`

Comment: The *don't* really work "partially", and you shouldn't try to use them that way. You're getting inline formatting identical to use of single backticks. When you type `\`\`\`abc\`\`\``, you're getting one *empty* inline block for the first `\`\``, then one inline block containing `\`abc\``, then one more empty inline block `\`\``. This is identical to just using `\`abc\`` or `\`\`\`\`\`abc\`\`\`\`\`` or `\`\`\`\`\`\`\`abc\`\`\`\`\`\`\``.  So long as you have an odd number of `\``'s, the leading and trailing ones are redundant and have no effect

Answer (score 9):

Your format works for me:

```
MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx)
    .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
    .build()

HtmlUnitDriver driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder.mockMvcSetup(mvc).javascriptEnabled(true).build()
```

This is only because this type of format was just recently introduced. [Very recently.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/323179) In other words, [status-undeclined](/questions/tagged/status-undeclined).

All posts are cached, so you will need to make a minor edit to make the formatting work on posts that existed before this feature was implemented.

Comment: @usr2564301 Like I said, posts are cached, which means that it doesn't recalculate the HTML until the post is edited.

Comment: @usr2564301 Given the amount of content on Stack Overflow, things don't always get fixed soon after posting. And some things only get fixed partially. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45236274/6083675) is a random post from 2017 that was trying to use code fences.